# Amp-carousel (slides type) sets on overflow hidden even when layout responsive is set to the component

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I am having an issue relating to the `amp-carousel`. Each carousel slide will have a different height based on the content that is relating to the product.

I have set my carousel to have layout responsive and set a height like so:

```
<amp-carousel width="367" height="635" layout="responsive" class="o-wrapper fabric-gallery" type="slides" controls loop>
```

I am assuming using layout responsive will set the height to auto.

Would using something like `flex-item` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [`flex-item`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2778) since it will take the available space based on the flexbox model.

> Notice that `height=100%` and `width=100%` are overridable defaults and are only there to ensure that the container indeed specifies `display: flex`. Alternatively, the element can force `display: flex` on the parent.

The `flex-item` it ensures that the element is not sporadically resized while also giving it a more flexible positioning options. It'd also allow the element to participate in the flexbox layouts.

Check this [example](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/layout-flex-item.amp.html) on how to implement it in your page.